# Why isn't this thank you comment too chatty?

Tags: discussion

[1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10552/certification-scores-published/10553#comment15056_10554) [2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10552/certification-scores-published/10553#comment15055_10553)

> thanks! much appreciated!

These comments add nothing of value. Why was my "too chatty" comment flag declined?

Under the [help center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), **When *shouldn't* I comment**:

> **Compliments** which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, up-vote it and [pay it forward](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer);

Comment: Short of awarding a bounty, leaving a comment is the only way for the asker to show their humanity.

Comment: @user320 Humans suck. They should not be human. Everybody knows kittens are better anyway.

Comment: (also upvoting is an option that doesn't clutter the page with useless crap)

Comment: Referring to the gratitude of the asker as "useless crap" is... interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken care of it just now.

Comment: 3 of what? Close paren?

Comment: No. The minimum answer needs to be 30 chars. The '3' was the 30th. I thought id end there. ^^. No one but me could ever get this.

Comment: This answer is too chatty.

Answer (score 3):

Out of interest was the comment from the asker? I don't think I saw this flag, but sometimes if it's the asker and it's the only comment to such effect I'm personally happy to let it slide — sure the thing to do first is mark it accepted and upvote, but a little courtesey can be a good thing when the model in general can sometimes come across as a bit brutal.

Comment: It was from the asker. Does it matter? Too chatty is too chatty.

Comment: Agree with Matt, especially as there is only one asker. (As opposed to a readership of many, resulting in "me too", "+1", "thanks")